# How to remove a long word from a string

Tags: php, regex

If a user types a really long string it doesn't move onto a 2nd line and will break a page on my site.  How do I take that string and remove it completely if it's not a URL?

Comment: you may want to look up the `<wbr>` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to remove what the user wrote? Instead, wrap it to a new line - there is a function in PHP to do that, called [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Comment: But remember to set 4th param to true so it actually cuts those overlong strings!

Comment: wordwrap will break the entire string, not just the long words.

Comment: You did not answer the question. Either change the question or change your answer.  There are infinite reasons to remove a long word. Don't assume you can imagine/predict every possible scenario/application till the end of time.  Maybe the 45 chracters of "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" is a reasonable limit for certain applications.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to remove the word, or do you just want to prevent it from making your page layout too wide? If the latter is more what you want, consider using CSS to manage the overflow.

For instance:

div {
   overflow:hidden;
}

will hide any content that exceeds the div boundary.

Here's more info on CSS overflow:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
// remove words over 30 chars long
$str = preg_replace('/\S{30,}/', '', $str);
```

edit: updated per Tim P's suggestion, \S matches any non-space char (the same as `[^\s]`)

Also here is a better way incorporating ehdv's suggestion to use wordwrap:

```
//This will break up the long words with spaces so they don't stretch layouts.
$str = preg_replace('/(\S{30,})/e', "wordwrap('$1', 30, ' ', true)", $str);
```

Comment: I suggest using /S instead of /w - this will also catch long strings with punctuation, numbers and other special characters.

Comment: $str = preg_replace('/(\S{30,})/e', "wordwrap('$1', 30, ' ', true)", $str);
What? You replace actual long strings with literal wordwrap command? Why would you do something like that?

Comment: The 'e' modifier evaluates the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

What if it is a really long URL? At any rate why not just match the text to a valid URL, and only accept those? Check out [some php-regex info on URLs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) and see how they work. The [Regular Expressions Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520694) has a good chapter on URL matching, as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Rob care in using REGEX. Performance lookout.